# the values on the y axis are in decreasing order in ggplot barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a bar chart using ggplot but the resulting graph is decreasing on the y-axis as supposed to increase:

```
data_mat_2 <- data.frame(data_mat_2)  
ggplot(data = data_mat_2, aes(x = data_mat_2$months, y = data_mat_2$numbers)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("")
```

id appreciate it, if you could give me some tips on how to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Seems like the problem is with your data. Please post some or all of it using `dput(data_mat_2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data_mat_2$numbers` is not ordered consistently at all - try converting it to a proper numeric data type with `as.numeric()` before plotting (I assume it's currently a factor/character string).